# Sitecore: Placeholder settings do not work when applied to a specific template

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm running Sitecore 6.5 and having some problems with placeholder settings.

It is my understanding that there are two ways to configure placeholder settings:

1. Globally (in the placeholder setting item)
2. On a template by template basis (as part of the standard values)

If I apply my settings globally, everything works as it ought to. However, if I apply the setting to the template itself, it has no effect.

I currently have a ticket with Sitecore Support about this issue, but was wondering if the community here had ever run into something like this before.

Comment: Can you try to give some more details? Like what you've set and where exactly, what you expected to happen and what is wrong? Screenshots could be helpful as well.

Comment: Jesan, did you get anywhere with this? Did the below answer help?

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. Your answer confirmed that the process I thought ought to work does not on my site. I currently have a support ticket with Sitecore and they are looking into my issue. I was planning on posting their answer (as well as any additional details they needed) here once they got back to me.

Thanks for checking on me!

Comment: No worries Jesan, do let us know the outcome. Always helpful to know what Sitecore support suggests as solution to various issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My particular issue was eventually solved by Sitecore support. As it turns out, in Sitecore 6.5 and earlier, mixed case placeholder names do not function correctly. They provided a patch dll to fix the behavior for our site.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it should work. Tried it locally on my Sitecore 6.5 install and it works.

Make sure of following:

1. That the template is inherited correctly, if you have multiple template inheritance.
2. Placeholder settings are specified properly on the Standard Values and other thing to watchout is if it takes parameter values.
3. (You probably know this but...) Use *Presentation >> Layout >> Details >> Layout Details >> Default >> Edit* on ribbon after selecting the item.
4. Lastly make sure the Allowed Controls are specified correctly (Renderings, Sublayouts, Web Controls, etc.) in your placeholder.
5. Last thing to check is if your code has a boolean that is hiding the
   placeholder. i.e. `FooPlaceholder.Visible = False;`

Let us know if any of the above helps.